# Filtering a query on a particular criteria like records for last 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider a table:

```
╔══════╦════════════╦═════════╦════════════════════╦═════════╗
║ Name ║ License No ║ Status  ║ Status_update_date ║ Address ║
╠══════╬════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════╬═════════╣
║ Jon  ║    1234    ║ Active  ║    01/01/2016      ║  aaaa   ║
║ Rick ║    5678    ║ Expired ║    31/11/2015      ║  xxxx   ║
║ Bob  ║    0987    ║ Expired ║    30/01/2016      ║  ssss   ║
║ Carl ║    3456    ║ Active  ║    03/12/2015      ║  qqqq   ║
╚══════╩════════════╩═════════╩════════════════════╩═════════╝
```

Status update date is the date when the status of the person is changed Active to Expiry in case of Expiry and SET in case of Active

I want to get the records for all active licences and licences expired in last 30 days other expired licences are to be ignored

Here is the expected result assuming the current date is `05/02/2016`:

```
╔══════╦════════════╦═════════╦════════════════════╦═════════╗
║ Name ║ License No ║ Status  ║ Status_update_date ║ Address ║
╠══════╬════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════╬═════════╣
║ Jon  ║    1234    ║ Active  ║    01/01/2016      ║  aaaa   ║
║ Bob  ║    0987    ║ Expired ║    30/01/2016      ║  ssss   ║
║ Carl ║    3456    ║ Active  ║    03/12/2015      ║  qqqq   ║
╚══════╩════════════╩═════════╩════════════════════╩═════════╝
```

One restriction is that the query should not contain `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `OR` condition for **status** and **Status_update_date** as they can't occur at same time.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE status  = 'Active'
OR (  status  = 'Expired'
      AND Status_update_date >= SYSDATE -30
   );
```

To get the current date, you could use `SYSDATE` or `CURRENT_DATE` given that the *timezones are same for the session and that of the OS of the database server*.

Comment: Nullifying the downvote(*As the downvoter didn't care to leave a comment*) +1

Comment: `SYSDATE` and `CURRENT_DATE` are **not** synonymous in Oracle. `SYSDATE` returns current date in database operating OS time zone whereas `CURRENT_DATE` returns current date in your session time zone.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Of course. Given that given that the timezones are same for the session and that of the OS of the database server. Added the explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myatble
WHERE Stauts  = 'Active' OR Expiration_DT > sysdate-30
```

Comment: I think I need to do the same for you too. Nullifying the downvote(As the downvoter didn't care to leave a comment) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE STATUS='ACTIVE' AND EXPIRATION_DATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY
```